# Создание декоративных элементов в фоне

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Я планирую на странице добавить несколько декоративных элементов с помощью JavaScript: треугольники, генерируемые случайным образом.

Эти элементы чисто декоративны, и я хочу, чтобы они создавались, как бы в фоновом режиме, и не препятствовали бы работе пользователя с уже созданными элементами страницы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Если просто повесить эту функцию на `Onload`, то ведь, по идее, пользователь толком не сможет работать с этой страницей, пока `Onload` не выполнится...

Comment: Я бы с помощью [`setTimeout()`](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout) вызывал раз в секунду ф-ю, добавляющую новый треугольник, до тех пор, пока кол-во треугольников не достигнет установленного порога.

Comment: Например, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/u7AR7/)